# Implementing secp256k1 (ECDSA) in PHP (for Bitcoin)

Tags: php, bitcoin, ecdsa, php-openssl

**To keen downvoters and/or closers: If you think this is offtopic for SO, kindly point me out other StackExchange site where this question would be more appropriate.**

---

How to implement ECDSA curve **secp256k1** in PHP?

Or rather: Are there any solutions - ie. includable specialized classes - already done?

I can see there are plenty of opensource libraries, classes and stuff available for other languages (JavaScript, Python,...) but I've just spent whole afternoon googling for some/any PHP solution and ... ***nothing!***.

This is for a bitcoin project of mine and **I need a way how to generate public key from private key** ... **and then I want to generate the final bitcoin address**.

**I know how to generate private key** (don't worry about it being random or not - not an issue here) and **I have both 256bit hexadecimal and WIF notations**. But the next step: coming up with a *public key* and then final *bitcoin address*, is kind of a problem to me, as I have literally zero cryptograph-ish background and I know the solution is to utilize secp256k1 somehow.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Random bytes
// $private_key = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
// But using brainwallet.org style to have easy comparison
$passphrase = "correct horse battery staple";
$private_key = hash('sha256', $passphrase);
var_dump ("PrivKey: $private_key");
// Bitcoin::privKeyToWIF from github.com/mikegogulski/bitcoin-php
$wif = Bitcoin::privKeyToWIF($private_key); 
var_dump ("WIF PrivKey: $wif");
// And now I don't know where to even start ...
```

**tl;dr How to implement this in PHP?** (..and *privKey->pubKey* conversion before that)

### https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2neg.png

I know about...

- http://github.com/mikegogulski/bitcoin-php .. Which is pretty neat and has lots of useful methods and ways how to control *bitcoind* via RPC, but unfortunately pure PHP method that could handle *privKey->pubKey* mechanism is missing.
- http://bitcoinphp.com/ .. I couldn't find it in there.
- *openssl extension in PHP*, but unfortunately the only digest method OPENSSL-PHP documentation is mentioning is 'ecdsa-with-SHA1', and correct me if I'm wrong, but I'd need 'ecdsa-with-SHA256', or something like that (?)
- I even tried to convert the algorithm from *bitcoinjs.js*, but with my crypto-knowledge I was unable to extract the gist of anything. I simply don't understand those curves and their bit operations and other spooky stuff.

**I'm looking for PURE PHP solution.** I'm not looking for using shell running bitcoind and then parse JSON for key pairs and then...

Why there is no piece of code that could handle this entirely in PHP? **OR IS THERE?!** :)

Comment: And if this deserves a downvote, you could share with the rest why exactly.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but you *do* ask for a solution in PHP without showing that you actually tried creating your own solution, which is sometimes frowned upon.

Comment: ...that said, I think this is an interesting question (that I wouldn't mind knowing the answer to myself). Unfortunately, I'm out of votes, so I couldn't `+1` this for you.

Comment: Oh, good point. But then again - I wouldn't know where to even start with implementing this magic. :)

Comment: OpenSSL needs a hack to support ecdsa-with-SHA256: https://forum.openvpn.net/topic8404-15.html

Comment: Constructive, thank you.

Comment: I started developing a PHP library that will achieve exactly this. It requires php >=5.4 and the php5-gmp extension to be installed.
You can look at the code here https://github.com/rgex/BitcoinECDSA.php
You can already provide a private key (256 hexa string) and it will generate for you a WIF, the public key and the uncompressed Bitcoin address corresponding. But please don't use it in production there is still a lot of things missing.

Comment: @JanMoritz thank you excellent!