# How to verify ecdsa-with-SHA256 signature with PHP?

Tags: php, sha, ecdsa

I have encountered the following issue while developing a secure system:

We receive some data which we have to verify by signature. The signature algorithm is ecdsa-with-SHA256, and [openssl_verify()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-verify.php) doesn't seem to have an option for that. Already tried searching for standalone PHP libraries like phpseclib - no luck either, ecdsa-with-SHA1 is the best option they seem to offer.

What would be an appropriate solution for that issue? Maybe I've missed some library that implements such functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `openssl_` currently supports ECDSA only with SHA1 digest (reefer to [`openssl_get_md_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-md-methods.php) output, position `[14]`). You'll need a workaround for this. From comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386230/implementing-secp256k1-ecdsa-in-php-for-bitcoin) (*closed as off topic, by the way)*, but it was focused on bitcoin implementations.

Comment: Even though I've already found that information, thanks for your answer. What would you consider the best practice then? Simply passing the data to some external c++\python script?

Comment: Yes, if I'd have to think of a workaround, surely would be an external small app only for that.

Comment: Since this answer seems the only correct one, I'll mark it as one. Thanks again!